# ListView not showing data in App Widget

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget, appwidgetprovider, android-remoteview

I'm trying to implement a simple collection widget for my application, i'm trying to show a `ListView` inside a widget but the `ListView` is stuck at Loading... and never finish loading, and i have data in the database and the listview is still stuck with it.

Here is the `onUpdate` method from my AppWidgetProvider class:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    int length = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++){
        RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,RViewsService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[x]);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        remote.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.list,intent);
        remote.setEmptyView(R.id.list,R.id.empty);
        remote.setTextViewText(R.id.title,Utilities.setDayOfWeek());
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Intent AddmateriaIntent = new Intent(context,AddMateria.class);
        PendingIntent pendingItentForButtonAddMateria = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,AddmateriaIntent,0);
        remote.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.add,pendingItentForButtonAddMateria);
        remote.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.empty, pendingItentForButtonAddMateria);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[x],remote);
    }
   super.onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
}
```

I could check and the method `onUpdate` finish its job without errors.
And here is the RemoteViewService and RemoteViewsFactory they also don't show error on logCat.

public class RViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {

```
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new RViewFactory(getApplicationContext(),intent);
}

class RViewFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    private DBAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Materia> materias;
    private Context context;

    public RViewFactory(Context context,Intent intent){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        adapter = new DBAdapter(context).openReadableDatabase();
        materias = new ArrayList<Materia>();
        Cursor cursor = adapter.query(Utilities.setDayAndTable(), new String[]{DBAdapter.ROW_SUBJECT,DBAdapter.ROW_COLOR_NAME,DBAdapter.ROW_COLOR_HEX}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    Materia materia = new Materia();
                    materia.setSubject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.ROW_SUBJECT)));
                    materia.setColor(new ColorObject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.ROW_COLOR_NAME)),
                            (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.ROW_COLOR_HEX)))));
                    materias.add(materia);
                    Log.d("log", "Data: " + materia.getSubject());
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        materias = null;
        adapter.close();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return materias.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int i) {
        RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        remote.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1,materias.get(i).getSubject());
        remote.setTextColor(android.R.id.text1,materias.get(i).getColor().getColor());
        return remote;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

And in the LogCat i cant find error or warnings when the Widget is loading, it only show when the cursor is being read (i've erased text from the LogCat because it was about the GC).

**Logcat**

```
05-02 12:54:30.796  21885-21885/schooltimetable.app D/cannon﹕ Data: Math
05-02 12:54:30.806  21885-21885/schooltimetable.app D/cannon﹕ Data: Theory
```

And i'm sure that the Cursor returns de data because i've log it in Logcat and it did as shown above.

And this is the **Manifest** snippet declaring the AppWidgetProvider and RemoteViewService:

```
    <receiver android:name="schooltimetable.app.appWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/cannon_widget" />
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".RViewsService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
```

I'm testing my app on **Nexus 7 (2012) : Android 4.4.2**

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the return count  of `getViewTypeCount` to 1.

`getViewTypeCount` is the number of types of Views that will be returned by the factory.

```
 @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem because I put custom view in list row, try to remove them if you have.