# Update widget through activity :Android

Tags: android, service, android-widget

Ok so I've an activity that receives notifications from facebook by pressing a button.Now I want that activity to send alert on my widget when ever a new notification comes from facebook. I cant find a reasonable way of achieving this. Do I need to put the code in broadcast receiver? or I've to call the activity in alarmManager from my widget? or anything else? Looking forward to some help..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom RemoteViewsService and bind to the widget. When you receive the notification , you can update the data in the widget through RemoteViewsService.

Check this question [ListView not showing data in App Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818300/listview-not-showing-data-in-app-widget/22820612#22820612) , on how to use RemoteViewsService