# Can I add custom List View in widget in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-appwidget

Actually i add a custom list View in my widget xml file. when i am running i program and trying to set widget on homescreen after the execution the it is giving me error . **Problem loading Widget**

Comment: Please post the `adb logcat` output

Comment: What does "custom list View" mean? Do you mean that you create a subclass of `ListView`? If so, that will not work.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818300/listview-not-showing-data-in-app-widget .let me know if you still see any issue